# Assignment grammar conflicting with λ-calculus application grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr, grammar, lambda-calculus

I am implementing an extended λ-calculus interpreter using ANTLR4 and it's C++ target. Here is the language grammar:

```
grammar lambda;

program: expression|;

expression:
    (Int | Bool)                                # literal
    | Identifier                                # variable
    | expression expression                     # application
    | Lambda Identifier '.' expression          # abstraction
    | Identifier '=' expression                 # assign
    | condition                                 # conditional
    | Operator expression expression            # binaryExpression
    | 'print' expression                        # printInstruction
    | '(' expression ')'                        # brackets;

body: expression;
condition: 'if' expression 'then' body 'else' body
    | '(' expression '->' body '|' body;

Lambda: '\\' | 'λ';
Bool : 'tru' | 'fls' | 'true' | 'false';
Int: [0-9]+;
Identifier: ('a' ..'z') ('a' ..'z' | '0' ..'9')*;
Operator:
    '+'
    | '-'
    | '*'
    | '/'
    | '<'
    | '>'
    | '<='
    | '>='
    | '==';

WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
```

I am constructing an AST using the visitor model, which will be evaluated separately. I have encountered an issue with the way ANTLR is parsing the input, and I'm not really sure even what to call it.

#### Issue 1

```py
// incorrect_association.lambda

y = 1
x = 1

Assignment ( y = ( Application ( Literal ( 1 ) ) ( Assignment ( x = ( Literal ( 1 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

The AST should be

```py
Assignment ( y = ( Literal ( 1 ) )
Assignment ( x = ( Literal ( 1 ) )
```

or

```py
Grouping (
    Assignment ( y = ( Literal ( 1 ) ),
    Assignment ( x = ( Literal ( 1 ) )
)
```

#### Issue 2

I suppose this may tie into the first issue: expressions across multiple lines are being read as `Application` expressions.

```py
// incorrect_application.lambda

x = 1
print x

Assignment ( x = ( Application ( Literal ( 1 ) ) ( PrintInstruction ( Identifier ( "x" ) ) ) ) )
```

The AST should be

```py
Assignment ( x = ( Literal ( 1 ) )
PrintInstruction ( Identifier ( "x" ) )
```

or

```py
Grouping (
    Assignment ( x = ( Literal ( 1 ) ),
    PrintInstruction ( Identifier ( "x" ) )
)
```

I am trying to have imperative-like constant assignments, with a functional-like execution. Eventually, the program should just be whatever `main = ...` (like Haskell). Is it possible to prevent the `Application` rule from matching two expressions that are on different lines, but continue to allow any other whitespace and parens?

#### Possible Solution

I was contemplating writing a preprocessor that would just throw semicolons on each line ending. I may need to do this anyway because I plan on adding

```
imports: 'import' Identifier | '(' imports ')';
```

as a grammar rule, and haven't found a nice solution for handling imports with ANTLR. If I were to go this route, how would I include `;` line endings in my grammar?

PS: I am very new to ANTLR, so any guidance would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want newlines to be significant, then let them pass through the lexical scanner.

```
WS: [ \t\r]+ -> skip;
NL: [\n];
```

Then you could define a program as a sequence of expressions terminated with newline characters:

```
program: ( expression NL )*;
```

If you want semicolons to work as well, just change the definition of NL:

```
NL: [\n;];
```

You'll also want to change `body` to accept multiple expressions, although it's not clear to me what kind of punctuation you will want to use. It's possible that

```
body: expression (NL expression)*;
```

will work for you, but it might produce unexpected results.

Your application syntax is highly ambiguous. I have no idea what Antlr will make of it, but I can't interpret it. If you have

```
+ a b c
```

That must be one of:

```
(+ a b) (c)
(+ a (b c))
(+ (a b) c)
```

But I don't see any indication of which of the three should be prefered. I would think that you would need to come up with a grammar which has more precise precedence.

(There is a reason Lisp and Scheme use parentheses :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the reply! λ-calculus is left-associative, so `(+ a (b c))` is preferred. I think adding the `NL` rule will do the trick! I will try it and get back to you :)

Comment: @Iain: Left associative would be `((+ a b) c)`, as I understand the meaning of associativity (although it's a little difficult to apply in this context.) For `b c` to be parsed as `(b c)` requires right-association of application to be preferred.

Comment: you are correct :D. I have had Church Encodings on the brain lately.

Comment: I got it working using your suggestion, but my visitor isn't called if there is an empty line from that point. Is there an easy fix for this? or does it warrant a new question?

Comment: Got it working with `program: ( expression NL )*  # instructionLine;` and `NL: [\n;]+;`. Thank you!

Comment: @Iain: I had made a mental note to mention the issue with empty lines and then I forgot about it. Either of `( expression? NL )*` or `( expression NL+ )*` should work.